# Use of .ini file and getting values from .ini file

Tags: ini, php-5.6

I've a file called config.ini and the location and contents are

```
/var/www/private/config.ini

    [database]
    servername=localhost
    username=root
    password=root
    dbname=database
```

calling this file in a database connection function. and the location is `/var/www/includes/connection.php`

```
function db_connect() {

    static $connection;    
    if (!isset($connection)) {
        $config = parse_ini_file("/var/www/private/config.ini",true);
        //$config = parse_ini_file("../private/config.ini",true);
        print_r($config);
        $connection = mysqli_connect($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);
    }

    if ($connection == false) {
        echo 'error';
        return mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        return $connection;
    }
}

// Connect to the database
$connection = db_connect();
```

But i'm not getting the values of config.ini or i couldn't print the whole file. Is there any mistake in this code? or anyone has any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find out the mistake!

string values must be in double quotes.

format of .ini file should be like

```
[database]
servername="localhost"
username="root"
password="root"
dbname="database"
```